# Identificar modelo do roteador via PHP ou Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

É possível identificar o modelo do roteador de uma pessoa através do PHP ou Javascript?

Queria que quando a pessoa acessasse uma página "X" o php ou javascript identificasse qual é o modelo do roteador dela e guardasse essa informação em txt ou BD.

Isso é possível ?

Comment: Se o PHP rodar dentro da rede da pessoa, e tiver acesso aos IPs internos, seria o caso de acessar a página do roteador e tentar identificar. Mas pra isso você teria que elaborar um método de verificação adequado para cada modelo. Pra simplificar, a melhor resposta seria "não, não tem e ainda bem que não, por uma questão de privacidade e segurança". Dentro de condições bem limitadas, e longe do ideal "dá pra identificar em alguns casos pontuais", mas em geral, seria uma porcaria o resultado.

Comment: Você teria um exemplo de como eu posso verificar nesses "casos pontuais"? Só pra eu ter uma ideia, pq nao faço nem ideia de como começar.

Comment: @Marcos acho que ele quis dizer: não comece porque não vai dar certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há diversos meios mas nenhum confiável pois nem sempre retornará o que se espera. Um exemplo de gambiarra que pode tentar fazer é obter o IP do gateway do usuário. Normalmente o IP do gateway é o IP que leva a página de administração do roteador. Mas note que só conseguirá acessar caso o usuário esteja na mesma faixa de IP do gateway e nem sempre o IP do gateway leva a página admin do roteador. Os roteadores permitem ao usuário definir uma faixa de IP customizada ou um conjunto pré definido que difere da faixa do gateway. Tornando esse método inviável. E mesmo que aceda ao gateway, não há garantia alguma de obter a informação que necessita.

Mas se quiser entender a ideia é, precisa obter o IP do gateway. Pode fazer isso com JavaScript usando permissões especiais de acesso via browser ou por meio de plugins JAVA (O JAVA é mero exemplo, pode ser outra linguagem).

Com o IP do gateway em mãos, a ideia é conseguir ler a página que retorna do protocolo HTTP.

Conseguindo a página, tente extrair as metatags ou o título da página. Muitos roteadores colocam o nome e modelo na tag `<title>`.

É esse o alvo. Obter o conteúdo da tag `<title>`.

Saliento novamente que é apenas um de diversos meios de alcançar o que pretende e ainda assim requer permissões de acesso para execução de plugins e scripts JavaScript que normalmente são bloqueados por normas básicas de segurança. E ainda tem a falta de garantia de que o nome e modelo do roteador estará descrito na página HTML conforme método citado acima.

obs: o meu roteador não exibe o nome, marca ou modelo na tag title. Ao invés disso exibe “クイック設定Web”.

Outros meios é usar funções de rede. Obviamente precisa de permissões para executar no usuário. Alguns roteadores retornam o modelo como nome de host ou DNS local. Normalmente o nome vem abreviado num padrão definido pelo fabricante. Mas como pode ver é também inseguro em relação a funcionalidade pois nem sempre terá essa informação e mesmo que consiga em alguns casos, ainda terá que interpretar as abreviaturas.

Um detalhe, pode descartar qualquer tentativa com usuários conectados em redes de telefonia 3G, 4G, 5G. E também usuários de dispositivos móveis como smartphones e tablets que obviamente não permitirão fazer nada disso. A menos que instalem explicitamente um aplicativo que extraia os dados da rede local.

No final das contas, terá um trabalho enorme com dezenas de gambiarras que não vale o retorno. É mais fácil um dromedário passar pelo orifício de uma agulha.